# I am running the next js app in tizen emulator, but the routing of the next js is not working in tizen. What is the solution for it?

Tags: next.js, routes, tizen, webos, react-routing

**Next js routing between the components is not working in the tizen emulator. What is the solution for it?**

We are running the next build file in the tizen software but it shows only index.html file of build folder and when we give routing it does'nt work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

nextjs used file based router, but tizen not supported it. You can use SPA(Single Page Application) for tizen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom logic to handle all pages without routing (single-page app). You need to manage the state of the current page and let it render into the DOM. Just show and hide the pages as you need to traverse your app.

```
return (
    {page === HOME && (<Home />)}
    {page === SEARCH && (<Search />)}
)
```